# hybris direct sql query with commit ON is not having affect

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I'm trying to run direct SQL queries on Hybris Admin Console (HAC) with commit ON but it is not having an effect on the record.

```
UPDATE users SET p_email = 'test@sql.com' WHERE p_uid = 'testuser@test.com'
```

[image: Direct sql query]

[image: search result]

Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: Verify it using select query `SELECT p_email FROM users WHERE p_uid='testuser@test.com'`

Comment: If you are getting updated value, your changes are saved already. To reflect it on your model (which is already cached!) you need to clear cache from `https://sagia.local:9002/hac/monitoring/cache`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Verify the updated value using select query

```
SELECT p_email FROM users WHERE p_uid='testuser@test.com'
```

2) Clear the cache to get it reflected in the Model as well

Go to **hac > monitoring > cache** and click on **Clear cache**

[image]